# How can I start Tomcat Remotely on Windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, batch-file

Is there a way to start Tomcat remotely with just moving start.bat?

For Example.  Say Tomcat was installed C:\"Program Files"\Tomcat and I want to be able copy and paste Start.bat into another directory (C:\tools\server).  From C:...server I want to be able to double-click on start.bat and automatically  start Tomcat.

Would I have to edit a specific line or multiple lines?

Which lines would I have to edit?  Would I have to edit line 25? (set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%  ....)

Comment: Why not make a second batch file that just starts it?

Comment: Why don't you create a l̶i̶n̶k̶  shortcut to this initial batch file?

Comment: awesome.  Great Idea.  That is exactly what I ended up doing.
(second batch file pointing to startup.bat)

Answer (score 0):

Create another batch script that simply starts it.

All you would need to do is to change the relative location of the Tomcat directory in the script.